# Can't mock method(Class<? extends SomeClass>)

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I'm trying mock a Enum:

```
public enum SomeEnum implements BaseEnum{

    SOME_VALUE("Description", SomeClass.class);

    private Class<? extends IConsignador> integracao;
    private String descricao;

    TipoIntegracao(String descricao, Class<? extends IConsignador> integracao){
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.integracao = integracao;
    }

    @Override 
    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public Class<? extends IConsignador> getIntegracao() {
        return integracao;
    }
}
```

And my mock:

```
SomeEnum mock = createMock(SomeEnum.class);
expect(mock.getIntegracao()).andReturn( (Class<? extends IConsignador>) eq(ClassWithOutPublicConstructor.class ) );
replay(mock);
```

But eclipse say:

```
The method andReturn(Class<capture#1-of ? extends IConsignador>) in the type IExpectationSetters<Class<capture#1-of ? extends IConsignador>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#2-of ? extends IConsignador>)
```

he suggested the cast, and still does not accept the value.
What can it be?

Comment: What makes you think you can mock an enum in the first place?  I would think you shouldn't be able to.  Enum instances shouldn't be createable by any means except by providing the enum constant at compile time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As with other things tricky to mock, consider extracting the interface out of your Enum and mocking the interface directly. Mocking an Enum is a bad idea because it breaks the general contract of the static and instance methods on your Enum (e.g. `ordinal()` and `values()`).

To the EasyMock point, EasyMock apparently has some trouble with bounded wildcards. Try using [this syntax](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/easymock/message/929):

```
EasyMock.<Class<? extends IConsignador>>expect(
    mock.getIntegracao())
    .andReturn(ClassWithOutPublicConstructor.class);
```

You also left an `eq` in your `thenReturn`, which EasyMock dislikes. Matchers are only for within `expect`'s parameter. Sorry I didn't see it before.

Comment: I thought this a great idea (why not I think of that!?). Still did not work. Now I only mock interface. But he's still not accepting `ClassWithOutPublicConstructor.class` (which implements the interface `IConsignador`). I believe the problem is in the return type `Class <? extends SomeInterface>`

Comment: Resolved!

Divide method that uses two methods in the enum. The first receives the enum, take a class and pass to the second method. So no need mocks (EasyMock) and I can pass the class straight to the second method. Your response was fundamental. Thanks.

Comment: @Falci I updated my answer, having figured out just now what it might be. Thanks for the accept all the same. Cheers!